# GameKit matchmaking sample?

Tags: iphone, ios, gamekit, game-center

Isn't there any GameKit matchmaking sample projects from Apple?
I couldn't find any - just one about leaderboards & achievements (called GKTapper)

Answer (score 2):

maybe [GKTank](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GKTank/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008918) apple sample code

Answer (score 0):

you may use this sample game: http://cocos2d-central.com/files/file/7-game-kit-data-sendreceive-demo-project/